# I want to concole.log the text of the h2 tag whenever users clicks the tag and when clicks another h2 tag it should display the text of that h2 tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to concole.log  the text of the h2 tag whenever users clicks the tag and when clicks another h2 tag it should display the text of that h2 tag the class and id  of  the tags are same..

Comment: If you have two elements with the same id, you have a problem.

Comment: id can be changeable, is there any way i can do it ?

Comment: Checkout if my answer helps you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this.

```js
$('h2').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2> Hello from first H2 </h2>
<h2> Hello from second H2 </h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('h2').forEach(h2 => {
    h2.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(this.textContent);
    });

});
```

```html
    <h2>h2 1</h2>
    <h2>h2 2</h2>
    <h2>h2 3</h2>
    <h2>h2 4</h2>
    <h2>h2 5</h2>
```